# Get all posts for custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy `how-to-guide-type` and I have some terms setup in this taxonomy.

I want to display ONLY the posts assigned to each taxonomy term.

I have the following but I can only seem to display posts for the first taxonomy term not for each different one:

```
        $returnable = [];
        $custom_terms = get_terms('how-to-guide-type');


        $query = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'cpt_how_to_guides',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'how-to-guide-type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $custom_terms[0]->slug,
                ],
            ],
        ]);


        if ($query->have_posts()) {
            $counter = 1;
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

                $returnable[] = [
                    'date' => get_the_date('d M Y'),
                    'title' => get_the_title(),
                    'link' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'content' => get_post_content(),
                    'count' => $counter
                ];
                $counter++;
            }
        }


        wp_reset_query();

        return $returnable;
```

I have tried to for each through the terms too but this displays all posts irrespective of which term they are assigned to. I want the query to be able to dynamically figure this out without having to add the slugs for the terms in the `terms =>` parameter.

Comment: How is your question different from just getting all the posts of a given taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to display posts assigned to a taxonomy (just a list of posts from each term in your taxonomy without displaying term information)

Get only terms IDs:

```
$custom_terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'how-to-guide-type', //your taxonomy
    'hide_empty' => true, //ignore terms without posts
    'fields' => 'ids' //return only terms ids
));
```

Now **$custom_terms** is an array of terms ids. Modify your tax_query like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'cpt_how_to_guides',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'how-to-guide-type',
            'terms' => $custom_terms, //array with terms ids of your taxonomy
            'operator' => 'AND' //display posts from all of these terms
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Also, you don't need to create a custom variable for a counter, your $query has a property for this purpose. Use **$query->current_post** instead of a **$counter** variable. It starts from zero.